# @PropertySource and @Value doesn't work in @WebListener annotated class

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, properties

I need to set the session timeout of my Spring mvc application. I have this code

```
@WebListener
@PropertySource("classpath:myapp.properties")
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Value("${session.timeout}")
    private int sessionTimeout;

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeout);
        log.debug("sessionTimeout: " + sessionTimeout);        
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

    }

}
```

while `@PropertySource("classpath:myapp.properties")` and     `@Value("${session.timeout}")` works in other classes, they doesn't work in my `SessionListener` class. Does anyone see what can be happening?

Comment: My guess, this is because your `SessionListener` isn't managed by `Spring-container`

Comment: Spring handles only `@Component`s, so mark your class with annotation `@Component` and it will be scanned and processed with all necessary handlers.

Comment: I have tried but with @Component does not work either